# Is it possible to have components other than List in ListActivity

Tags: android

By using the following code.

**BuyActivity.java**

```
public class BuyActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.transaction_list_view);        
        OrderAdapter orderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.custom_row_view, new ArrayList<Object>());
        setListAdapter(orderAdapter);        
        orderAdapter.add(new Object());
        orderAdapter.add(new Object());    
    }
}
```

**transaction_list_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
    </ListView>
    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:text="No data"
    />  
</LinearLayout>
```

**custom_row_view.xml**

Please refer to [custom_row_view.xml](https://github.com/yccheok/jstock-android/blob/c89aede414fd73e45475cf5b0abd1d5cc1164150/res/layout/custom_row_view.xml)

I was able to get the following outcome.

[image]

Besides list, I would also like to have a static label at the bottom of ListActivity.

I try

**transaction_list_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
    </ListView>
    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:text="No data"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:text="THIS IS TOTAL STATIC LABEL"
    />  
</LinearLayout>
```

But I am getting

[image]

What my expectation is

[image]

Is there anything I had missed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have indicated that your `ListView` is supposed to `fill_parent` in the vertical orientation, leaving no room for your other widgets. Your weight is being ignored. You probably want to have your `android:layout_height` be `0dip` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of the static textview to wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try Relative Layout to just set the static label anchored to the bottom of the screen. If that's not what you meant, I would try to help you further on. Good luck